# How to remove shadow from material Chip android view?

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

[image]

I use android material `Chip` view

It seems it has a shadow in the lower part.

Which attribute to way can I use to remove any chance of bottom shadow?

Comment: I can't see the shadow.. Maybe a layout with more contrast?

Comment: I changed the screenshot

Comment: I can't see the shadow either, I mean... it's very subtle. Does it take an `elevation=0dp` or does that not do anything?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini can you answer and i will accept your answer?

Comment: I can't see the elevation. If you use a white background and a stroke=1dp you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a drop shadow, use `elevation=0dp` and the component should not render the *fake* shadow.

Answer (score 11):

I can't see the shadow in normal state but found in pressed state. And that should be eliminated using **stateListAnimator** attribute. Please check:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```